# Windows 10 not booting in dual boot with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I have recently installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu (Linux Mint). I was able to boot into both  systems, but I had to restart Windows. After this, Windows does not boot. It shows the black screen with the small wheel, and then it gets black, but the computer is running (I have to force shutdown).

I am able to work start Linux correctly, but it is not able to mount them unless I first use `ntfsfix`.

I have Fastboot disabled. I am able to run Windows in safe mode, from where I checked that hibernation is disabled.

EDIT: I suspect it has something to do with the hibernation files that Windows creates, because I need to delete them (using `ntfsfix`) in Linux in order to use the drives. However, hibernation is disabled in Windows. 
Also, if this helps I am able to boot Windows into safe mode (I get the menu after trying to boot it 3 times).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using the boot-repair module. Maybe it can fix your thing if there is lone booting problem.
more info here 
[boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I tried doing the recommended repair, but it made no difference. As I said, I think the problem is that Windows did not unmount the drives correctly, but I don't know how to fix it, since I have already disabled Fastboot and hibernation.